# g++ No such file or directory?

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-errors, g++

I wrote:

```
g++ -std=c++11 –DNDEBUG –Wall *.cpp
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
-bash-4.2$ g++ -std=c++11 –DNDEBUG –Wall *.cpp
g++: error: –DNDEBUG: No such file or directory
g++: error: –Wall: No such file or directory
```

why is that?

Comment: Did you copy the commands from some webpage or from some document in Word or any other office suite? They tend to mess around with some characters. Quotes, dashes, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the character `–` instead of `-`

```
printf("%d\n%d\n", '–','-' );
```

Output:

```
14844051
45
```

https://onlinegdb.com/-EnhxljQy

Comment: I didn't get it... you wrote same one twice

Comment: No, they are different.

Comment: @Dano `printf("%d %d", '–','-' );` They may look the same in your web browser font.